# Convert markdown to json in R

Tags: json, r, markdown

Here are the steps I would like to execute:

1. Read a markdown file (see below) into R
2. Convert the markdown text to JSON
3. Send the JSON in an API POST call

Eg. markdown text file:

````
## This is a list

+ one
+ two
+ three

#### Do a thing
```coffee
points <- rnorm(10)
plot(points)
```

#### Do something else

![](someimage)
````

Steps 1 and 3 are easy, but step 2 is the one I don't get. A call to `rjson::toJSON` or `RJSONIO::toJSON` doesn't format the output JSON correctly. Does anyone know of a way to do this. [This README on github](https://github.com/scottstanfield/markdown-to-json/blob/master/README.md) has an example of what seems like a nice markdown to JSON conversion.

Comment: I don't think that github page you've linked to really converts markdown to JSON, it just grabs YAML data from the top of markdown files. Is there some other standard for converting markdown to JSON that you're aware of?

Comment: You're right, that's a bad example. No, I'm not aware of any.

Comment: How do you want your json file to look? Creating a json file containing just the text of your markdown file is easy, but I suppose you want something different. If you want your json file to contain the structure of your markdown file, it might be easier to first convert to html (you then have the tree-like structure of your document) and then parse the html document using the xml package.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: It turns out Pandoc can convert markdown to JSON in a way that retains the structure. If you're not familiar with Pandoc, you should definitely have a look at it.

Comment: @Marius Good idea. I am aware of and use Pandoc, though didn't think of that. I do need a solution totally within R though.

Comment: @JanvanderLaan Good idea, I will give that a shot. Yes, I do want to retain the structure of the markdown file as I am trying to create a Github gist, but they don't allow file uploads, only JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rCharts has a couple of utility functions that can do this easily. I am assuming your Rmd file is saved as `test.Rmd`. You can view the published gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/5957708)

```
require(rCharts)
payload = create_gist('test.Rmd', description = 'Testing Md to Gist')
post_gist(payload, viewer = 'http://gist.github.com/')
```

Is this what you were looking for?

UPDATE: If you want to update the gist you created, you can use the `update_gist` function, and pass it the gist id.

```
update_gist(payload, id, viewer = 'http://gist.github.com/')
```

You can use `options(github.username = ..., github.password = ...)` if you don't want to enter your username and password in your R console.

Comment: Does that retain the structure of the markdown file? i.e., does it look the same in the gist?

Comment: I think so, did you check the link to the published gist?

Comment: We are working on a R wrapper for the github API, in case you're interested: https://github.com/ropensci/gitr

Comment: Carlos Scheidegger and Simon Urbanek are also working on a wrapper which is fairly mature https://github.com/cscheid/rgithub